# How to make a BTreeSet from a slice and a manually constructed element?

Tags: rust

e.g.

```rs
match my_slice {
  [head, rest @ ..] => BTreeSet::from([convert(head), *rest])
}
```

getting errors like "expected usize, found slice" pointing at `*rest`.

Some of my other attempts

```rs
[[convert(head)], *rest].concat()
```

> expected array of 1 element, found slice

```rs
[&[convert(head)], *rest].concat()
```

> expected reference, found slice

```rs
[&[convert(head)], rest].concat()
```

> expected array of 1 element, found slice

How can I make a collection from a literal element and a slice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is probably to do it in two steps:

```
let mut s = BTreeSet::from_iter (rest);
s.insert (head);
```

If you want a one-liner, you can go through an iterator:

```
let s = BTreeSet::from_iter (rest.iter().chain (std::iter::once (head)));
```

Comment: In the first case why does it have to be `mut`?

Comment: @minseong if it wasn't `mut` then you couldn't call `s.insert (head)`

Comment: In my actual code, I'm getting an error `the trait `From<&[(usize, Box<Expression>)]>` is not implemented for `BTreeSet<_, _>`. Is my best solution to insert the items of `rest` one-by-one too?

Comment: Actually it needs to be `from_iter` and not `from`. See edited answer.